# Proof of Ehresmann's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In Huybrechts' book *Complex geometry: An introduction* p.269, Proposition 6.2.2, the author gives a proof of the following theorem

> (Ehresmann)
> Let $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ be a proper family of differential manifolds. If $B$ is connected, then all fibers are diffeomorphic.

His proof can be summarised as

> Step 1:
> Connect any two points of $B$ by a smooth arc, we may assume that the base $B$ is an interval $(-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$. Then we only need to show that the fibers $X_0\cong X_1$.
> Step 2:
> By the submersion condition, locally in $\mathcal X$, the map $\pi$ looks like the projection $\mathbb R^{m+1}\to \mathbb R$, so we can lift the vector field  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ on $B$ to the local chart $\mathbb R^{m+1}$.
> Step 3:
> By compactness, there exist finitely many open sets $U_i\subset \mathcal X$ covering the fiber $X_0$ such that  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ can be lift to a vector field $v_i$ on $U_i$. Using a partition of unity, one constructs in this way a vector field $v$ on $\cup_iU_i$ that projects to $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ on some neighborhood of $0\in(-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$.
> Step 4:
> Since the family is proper, there exists a point $\tau>0$ such that $X_{\tau}$ is contained in $\cup_iU_i$. Using the compactness of $[0,1]$, it suffices to show that $X_0$ and $X_{\tau}$ are diffeomorphic. A diffeomorphism $X_0\to X_{\tau}$ is provided by the flow associated to the vector field $v$.

My question lies in Step 4: for a proper family, why does it suffice to show that $X_0$ and $X_{\tau}$ are diffeomorphic?

As we know, Kähler property is stable under small differential deformations, then we can also find a $\tau>0$ such that $X_{\tau}$ is Kähler, in this way any deformation of $X$ is Kähler, which is obviously a mistake by a result of Hironaka.

Then why does this method apply to Step 4 of the proof?

Comment: It is not enough to show that they are diffeomorphic. He is showing that we can provide a fiber preserving diffeomorphism between $X_0 \times I$ and an open set of $X$ containing $X_0$, $I$ an interval. So $X$ is locally trivial, a fiber bundle over the interval.

Comment: Since all fibers are diffeomorphic, all fibers are diffeomorphic to a Kaehler manifold just when one fiber is a Kaehler manifold. But they are only diffeomorphic as real manifolds, not as complex manifolds. The complex structure can vary, and does in many elementary examples, already on complex surfaces.

Comment: @BenMcKay, for the diffeomorphism $F:X_0\times I\to \mathcal X;(x,t)\mapsto F(x,t)$, let $F_t(x):=F(x,t)$, then $F_t:X_0\to X_t$ provides a diffeomorphism between $X_0$ and $X_t$, which implies all the fibers over $B$ are diffeomorphic, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is right. But $F_t$ need not be holomorphic, since the vector field is produced using a partition of unity, so only $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: @BenMcKay, but I don't think it suffices to prove $X_0$ and $X_{\tau}$ are diffeomorphic for any $\tau>0$, for example, if we have proved $X_0\cong X_{\frac{1}{2}}\cong X_{\frac{3}{4}}\cong\cdots\cong X_{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}$, then we can't get the conclusion $X_0\cong X_1$, right?

Comment: it is not enough to prove that the fibers are diffeomorphic, as far as I can see, because we need to prove that there is a trivialization simultaneously of all fibers to prove triviality. Think of a nontrivial bundle, like the Moebius strip. But also, you are right that a sequence of fibers of a map can be all diffeomorphic without the limit fiber being diffeomorphic to any of them.

Comment: @BenMcKay, so you mean Huybrechts' proof contains a gap and it makes his proof invalid?

Comment: To prove the result stated, that all fibers are $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphic, his proof is fine. He splits up his interval into finitely many subintervals, and proves diffeomorphisms one step at a time through each of these subintervals. What I should have written is that the stronger result, which is what is usually called Ehressmann's theorem, states that the map is a $C^{\infty}$ fiber bundle, for which we need to ensure the local triviality.

Comment: @BenMcKay, thanks, I know where my problem lies in now: local triviality is transitive from 0 to 1 since any compact set can be covered by finitely many open sets, while local stability is not necessarily transitive between arbitrarily two points in a line.

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly, but this situation looks easier to me. Consider the bad case, where $X_0$ is diffeomorphic to $X_{a_1},X_{a_2},\dots$ and the points $a_1<a_2<\dots$ approach a limit $b$, with $X_b$ not diffeomorphic to $X_0$. Then the argument used for $X_0$ could be applied to $X_b$ in the reverse direction to get $X_b$ diffeomorphic to $X_c$ for any $c<b$ that is sufficiently close to $b$. But that would include some $a_n$ as a possible $c$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, I think the condition $a_1<a_2<\dots$ approach a limit $b$ is not easy to achieve, we still need to cover the compact interval $[a,b]$ by finitely many  open intervals and apply the local triviality.